# Overwritten Wordpress parent theme jquery.bxslider.css

Tags: php, css, wordpress, parent-child

I have been searching over 2 hours but did not find the similar solution. I would like to overwrite the jquery.bxslider.css in my parent theme.
The parent theme directory(just brief example):

parent_theme: **css**    :font-awesome.min
                         :responsive
                        :jquery.bxslider
              **style.css**;
              **functions.php**;

The child theme directory:
              **css**: jquery.bxslider
              **style.css**;
              **functions.php**

I did the child theme according to the updated Wordpress instruction
https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

I copied the jquery.bxslider.css from parent theme and pasted to the child theme under the folder css, then I changed some styles in the copied css.

I tried several ways to overwrite the parent theme but failed. I suppose it's the problem of my functions.php in the child theme. Any suggestions? Appreciate it in advance. Here is my child theme functions:

```
           <?php
             add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
             function theme_enqueue_styles() {
              wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() .        
             '/style.css' );
              wp_enqueue_style('child-style',get_templete_directory_uri().'/css/jquery.bxslider.css');
             }
             function dequeue_unwanted_css(){
               wp_dequeue_style('jquery.bxslider');
               wp_deregister_style('juqery.bxslider');
            }
          add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','dequeue_unwanted_css',100);
        ?>
```

Comment: Tks serenesat for edit my post:-)

Comment: if you want to dequeue it you need to post the way it was queued. If you just want to overrule a few style rules, enqueue it with a prority of 100

Comment: @David, tks for your reply. Can you give more explanations? Now I have copied responsive.css and jquery.bxslider.css in my child theme css folder. Plus the style.css under child theme. I took away the dequeue and put the enqueue priority like this    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles',100 ); It did not work. The responive css did not work. Tks!

Comment: ok, solved.  Saw some codes and modified it.